# Authenticate from command line error

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to Authenticate  from command line, but doesn't seams to work well.
please check my code and let me know where I went wrong.

```
<?php

echo "enter your username\n";

$username = fgets(STDIN);

echo "your password\n";

$password =  fgets(STDIN);

echo "enter your new password\n";

$newpassword = fgets (STDIN);

//connecting to database

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","sqldata","sqldata") or die(mysql_error());

//selecting our database

$db_select = mysql_select_db("accounts", $db) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query ("select * from uptable where username ='$username'");

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$oldpassword = $result['password'];

if ($password != $oldpassword)
{

echo "error";

}

else
{

mysql_query("update uptable set password = '$newpassword' where username ='$username'");

echo "Your Password has been successfully changed";

}

?>
```

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to SQL injections. Also, you shouldn’t store passwords in plain-text.

Comment: mysql_* functions are no longer used for some issues such as security, you may want to learn **PDO** or MVCs **e.g. CodeIgniter , cakePHP**

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt work? like is there an error? if yes, what does it tell?

Comment: when i supply username and password and newpassword it go to "echo error";

Comment: Im sure my username and password is right, it should update the database for the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Change all the `fgets()` assignments to use `trim()`, e.g.:

```
$username = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

The string returned by `fgets()` includes the newline, but the names and passwords in the database presumably don't.

Comment: Did you try to use `var_dump()` on your variables to see what they contain? How did you try to debug this before posting?

Comment: i have entered correct username and password, it echo ; "Your Password has been successfully changed"; and i did for the same but wrong username password it echo error;. i don't know about var_dump() and how  to use it. sorry.

Comment: Where did you learn to program PHP if you didn't learn about var_dump? It's one of the most important functions for debugging. Read the manual.

Comment: Thank you for your information I have googled about var_dump and got it.
I have another question.
How to get the return value of ping if its succeed or failure, I mean its 0 or 1

Comment: That has nothing to do with this, please start a new question.

Comment: im sorry to ask but for the past one hour in unable to post question, How to get the return value of ping if its succeed or failure i mean 0 or 1. i keep gettting error how to format!!!

Comment: Third argument to `exec()` is a variable that will be filled in with exit status of the command. It will be 0 for success, non-zero for failure.

Comment: `exec("ping www.google.com", $output, $status); if ($status == 0) { echo "www.google.com is up");}`

Comment: It's a required argument to the function, read the documentation.